# masm32 code shows error "A2206"

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

the following code segment is supposed to walk the `InInitializationOrderModuleList` inside the `PEB` and return the base address of kernel32.dll. However, when I try to `Console assemble and link` the following code I get the error stating that there is a `missing operator in expression`.

```
.486                                                     
option casemap :none                    

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.code
start:
call main
exit

main proc
mov eax, large fs:30h
mov eax, [eax+0Ch]
mov esi, [eax+1Ch]
lodsd
mov eax, [eax+8]
print str$(eax)
ret
main endp

end start
```

So, I changed the line as :-

`mov eax, fs:30h`

and the error I get is `error A2108: Use of register assumed to ERROR`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out, adding `assume fs:nothing` solves the problem.